Graphical analysis of residuals
For an electricity experiment, I have collected data on the charging and discharging of a capacitor. Using the data and scipy.curve_fit, I have fitted the theoretical models. Now, I need to validate the regression. Using residuals graphics, i have the following graphics. My question is, are this residuals graphics supposed to look like this? And, what other method can i use to validate the regression? The $R^2 $ coefficient should work?
[
This are the theoretical models
$V = V_0(1-e^{-t/RC)} \\
V = V_0e^{-t/RC}$

Very clearly the theoretical models don't describe the data very well at all (they "don't fit" the data). There's something going on with the data that the models are simply not capturing. If there were no reports of convergence issues, it might be worth considering what might be happening with the measurements that are not in the models. In addition to the lack of fit of the conditional mean, the usual nls assumption of constant error variance is plainly incorrect. Since these are time series you should also consider that the usual assumption of independence would be highly suspect.

As a result of the variance issue at the least, even without the lack of fit of the conditional mean, your estimates may not be particularly efficient; and estimated standard errors will be wrong.

What is causing the sharp breaks around time = 250 and 300 in your residuals? Also, there appear to be some nonlinearities present, and given what Glen mentioned, you may need to consider the time series nature of this problem when fitting, such as autocorrelation. It may also help to show exactly how you fit this model since that isn't completely clear from the question.
